# Two Sum III - Data structure design

Tags: java

My solution is failing because of timelimit exceeding. How do i improve the following solution for leetcode question.

https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum-iii-data-structure-design/description/

Design and implement a TwoSum class. It should support the following operations: add and find.

add - Add the number to an internal data structure.
find - Find if there exists any pair of numbers which sum is equal to the value.

Example 1:

```
add(1); add(3); add(5);
find(4) -> true
find(7) -> false
```

code:

```
class TwoSum {

Set<Integer> nums = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> res = new HashSet<>();
/** Initialize your data structure here. */
public TwoSum() {

}

/** Add the number to an internal data structure.. */
public void add(int number) {

    for( Integer s : nums)
    {
       res.add(s+number) ;
    }

    nums.add(number);
}

/** Find if there exists any pair of numbers which sum is equal to the value. */
public boolean find(int value) {

     if(res.contains(value))
           return true;


      else
        return false;
    }
}

    /**
     * Your TwoSum object will be instantiated and called as such:
     * TwoSum obj = new TwoSum();
     * obj.add(number);
     * boolean param_2 = obj.find(value);
     */
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving functioning code belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Michael I think we need to clarify whether the code works or not on its own first, if it doesn't work on its own then it's offtopic on Code Review; otherwise, it might be on topic.

Comment: @ThomasWard "My solution is failing because of timelimit exceeding." There. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach will attempt to add O(n<sup>2</sup>) values to the `res` `Set`.

Explanation:

When the 1st number is added, you add 0 values to `res`.
When the 2nd number is added, you add 1 value to `res`.
When the 3rd number is added, you add 2 values to `res`.
...
When the n'th number is added, you add n-1 values to `res`.

This gives you 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n-1 = O(n<sup>2</sup>), which is inefficient when `n` is large.

You can try a different approach. Eliminate the `res` `Set`. Store the input numbers in a `HashSet<Integer>`:

```
Set<Integer> nums = new HashSet<>();
```

This makes `add` trivial. Just do `nums.add(number)`, which takes `O(1)` time.

Now, for `find`, iterate over the elements of the `Set` and for each element `x`, check if `nums.contains(vaule-x) && (value-x != x)`. Return true if you find such `x`. This will take `O(n)` time.

The second condition `(value-x != x)` will prevent false positives. However, if the same number can be added twice, it might cause false negatives. To support duplicate numbers you'll have to store additional data for numbers that were added twice.

Comment: Still not working. I used sets for both. Test case 14/16 is failing as before. Its a long input

Comment: @maeo How long is the input? And how fast should it execute?

Comment: I think its because of the for loop

Comment: @maeo the input will have lots of add() and find() - I dunno how fast - its their test cases

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Golang using a hash map. Space complexity is O(n) and time complexity is O(1) for Add and O(n) for Find.

```
type TwoSum struct {
    data map[int]struct{}
}

func New() *TwoSum {
    return &TwoSum{
        data: make(map[int]struct{}),
    }
}

// Add the number to the internal data structure.
// Time complexity: O(1)
func (t *TwoSum) Add(num int) {
    t.data[num] = struct{}{}
}

// Find if there exists any pair of numbers which sum is equal to the value.
// Time complexity: O(n)
func (t *TwoSum) Find(target int) bool {
    for x := range t.data {
        if _, ok := t.data[target-x]; ok && x != target-x {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```